# Parse netcat output before sending?

Tags: shell, sh, netcat, busybox

For experimental and educational purposes, I am creating an extremely small and simple web server using only netcat.

currently i have

```bash
HTTP_RESPONSE="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n Hello"
{ echo -ne "$HTTP_RESPONSE"; } | nc -l -p 8080
```

What works correctly. However, suppose instead of "Hello" I wanted to send the nc output? Which returns the request header "Get, Host, etc." How could I do this in the same connection, in the same command?

I researched a lot but didn't get a satisfactory answer, almost all involve using nc a second time.

Comment: Look into coprocesses. Beyond that, I'm not sure the question is specific enough to be answerable in its current state ("want to send the nc output" -- but there's no complete output until nc exits; or are you saying you want to write an echo service? -- if that's what you want, "netcat echo service" as a search should find plenty of examples).

Comment: yes, i found a possible solution, but in bash, and im limited to busybox ash https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345383/netcat-respond-to-client-w-their-ip

Comment: So, i managed to get something with mkfifo. If i cat "e" instead of echo -ne response, and add >> xd.txt (as example) at the end of nc, the xd file will be created, with the full header, and will wait for the fifo file. so, it is a progress, the header indeed come before ending the connection

Comment: Why have you tagged the question `bash` if bash solutions aren't acceptable?

Comment: BTW, using `echo -ne` when you don't know your shell is bash is a bad idea (on strictly POSIX-compliant sh implementations, `echo -e` writes `-e` as output; and the behavior of `echo -n` is deliberately left unspecified by the standard). `printf '%b' "$HTTP_RESPONSE"` is much more portable. See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803) and [the POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), particularly including the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.